# Are some badges not available to be followed on the new profile "badges" box?

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page, badge-tracking

my question / request is about some badges that still can not be followed in the "badges" box of the profile. For instance pundit and taxonomist between others. Would it be possible to add them in the future?

I have been reading previous questions at Meta about how to follow badges and in the past the statistics site was the reference, I understand that for those tags still is the reference, but with the new (very cool!) profile I thought that it would not be necessary. Would it be possible for the near future?

Thank you!

(if this was asked before about the new profile I will remove the question)